# How can I make my program go back to a "main menu" after a subroutine?

Tags: fortran

I am making a physics calculator in Fortran and I have run into a problem. Recently I had some assistance with my code that makes it possible to do, say, a speed calculation, and then go back to the menu to do a time calculation. However, I just added 2 other settings (E= mc2 and current/charge/time), with another menu to choose which one you want to use. My current code (which I will input below) only takes you back to the calculation menu. How would I go about making it so that after you click a button you go back to the main menu?

```
module kinematics
implicit none
real :: t, d, s

contains

subroutine time_from_distance_and_speed()
print *, 'Input distance in metres'
read *, d
print *, 'Input speed in metres per second'
read *, s 
t = d / s
print*, 'Time is ', s 
end subroutine

subroutine distance_from_speed_and_time()
print *, 'Input speed in metres per second'
read *, s
print *, 'Input time in seconds'
read *, t 
d = s * t
print*, 'Distance is ', d
end subroutine

subroutine speed_from_time_and_distance()
print *, 'Input distance in metres'
read *, d 
print *, 'Input time in seconds'
read *, t 
s = d / t
print *, 'Speed is ', s
end subroutine

end module
module electronics 
implicit none
real :: Q, I, T 

contains

subroutine charge_from_current_and_time()
print *, 'Input current in amps'
read *, I
print *, 'Input time in seconds'
read *, T 
Q = I * T
print*, 'Charge is ', Q 
end subroutine

subroutine current_from_charge_and_time()
print *, 'Input charge in coulombs'
read *, Q
print *, 'Input time in seconds'
read *, T 
I = Q/T
print*, 'Current is ', I
end subroutine

subroutine time_from_current_and_charge()
print *, 'Input current in coulombs'
read *, Q 
print *, 'Input charge in amps'
read *, I 
T = Q/I
print*,'time is ', T
end subroutine
end module
module energy
implicit none
real :: e, m, c 

contains

subroutine energy_from_mass_and_lspeed()
print *, 'Warning- speed of light rounded to 300000000'
read *,
print *, 'Input mass in kilograms'
read *, m
c = 300000000
e = m * c * c
print*, 'Energy is ', e 
end subroutine
end module
program bike
use kinematics
use electronics
use energy
implicit none
integer :: gg, pp

print *, 'Press 0 for speed, distance, and time. Press 1 for current, charge and time. Press 2 for E= mc^2'
read *, pp

if ( pp == 0 ) then
do while(.true.)
    print *, 'Press 1 for speed, 2 for distance, and 3 for time'
    read *, gg
    if(gg == 1) then
        call speed_from_time_and_distance
    else if(gg == 2) then
        call distance_from_speed_and_time
    else if(gg == 3) then
        call time_from_distance_and_speed
    end if
    print *, 'Press 5 to exit the console, or press 4 to do another calculation'
    read *, gg    
    if(gg== 5) then
        exit
    end if
end do
end if

if ( pp == 1 ) then
do while(.true.)
    print *, 'Press 1 for charge, 2 for current, and 3 for time'
    read *, gg
    if(gg == 1) then
        call charge_from_current_and_time
    else if(gg == 2) then
        call current_from_charge_and_time
    else if(gg == 3) then
        call time_from_current_and_charge
    end if
    print *, 'Press 5 to exit the console, or press 4 to do another calculation'
    read *, gg    
    if(gg== 5) then
        exit
    end if
end do
end if

if ( pp == 2 ) then
do while(.true.)
        call energy_from_mass_and_lspeed
    print *, 'Press 5 to exit the console, or press 4 to do another calculation'
    read *, gg    
    if(gg== 5) then
        exit
    end if
end do
end if
end program
```

Comment: Have you discovered [nested loops](https://fortran-lang.org/learn/quickstart/operators_control_flow#loop-constructs-do) yet? They're very powerful, and will certainly let you do what you want here. Can you see how? If not, I can give you a few more details. (I'll avoid just giving the full answer, as you appear to be doing this to learn)

Comment: Gratuitous comment - `do while(.true.)` is a long way of writing `do`.

Comment: I got some help with the code from someone else on StackOverflow. This is a really useful comment! I will be sure to change it in my code from now on.

Comment: veryreverie- thanks so much for the link. It looks like nested loops will do the job. I also appreciate you giving me a link to help me learn, rather than just copy/pasting some code you've written.

Comment: @the_spider_collector: do post your own answer when you have figured it out.

Comment: OK I will be sure to do that